# Show/Hide fields with a struts2 checkbox

Tags: java, javascript, struts2

I would like to show/hide fields based on whether a struts2 checkbox is checked or not. Here is my code:

```
<s:checkbox label="Show/Hide" name="showHide" />
<s:textfield required="false" label="Extra Details" name="person.extraDetails" />
```

So when the user checks "showHide" then it should show "person.extraDetails". When they uncheck it should hide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lot of way to achieve this

sample with jquery:

```
<div  style="display: none;" id="divHideID">
<s:textfield required="false" label="Extra Details" name="person.extraDetails" />
</div>
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#showHide").click(function () {
        $("#divHideID").toggle();
        });
</script>
```